# Flag button disappears after flagging as a moderator

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, moderators

When I flag an answer as a ♦ moderator, the flag button/link becomes hidden. Granted, it's not an option I use very often, but flagging as VLQ/NAA might work if you want the community to decide on the fate of a post, and flagging for moderator attention might work as a means of communication to your colleagues.

[image]

What happens under water is that the flag button element gets a `display: none;` style. This doesn't happen when flagging as a regular user.

<sub>(Tested on the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Mojave; I'm sure that there are no userscripts involved.)</sub>

Comment: You *sure* you don't have any scripts or content-blockers running? I don't have a Mac to test with, but can't reproduce this on Firefox or Chrome on Windows.

Comment: On Firefox I've got all sorts of scripts and uBlock running; Safari is completely blank regarding plugins. However, I can't reproduce the issue anymore, so I'm voting to close it now. Strange, I've seen it happen for three consecutive days ...

Comment: Who knows then. Could've been a transient bug (although I don't see anything touched recently that would've either caused or fixed it). Or, I donno. [maybe you unplugged a USB mouse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381254/has-the-padding-on-code-blocks-been-increased/381280#comment677734_381280)...